# Is there a ICEfaces Maven archetype for NetBeans or Eclipse?

Tags: java, netbeans, maven-2, icefaces, maven-archetype

The [NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org/) IDE still seems to offer [Maven](http://maven.apache.org) Archetypes only for [Apache MyFaces](http://myfaces.apache.org/) or the "deprecated" [WoodStock JSF framework](https://woodstock.dev.java.net/index.html). For future development or migration of existing Woodstock projects, Sun is officially endorsing ICEfaces  as the replacement technology for Woodstock.

I have not yet found a Maven Archetype which would set up a new Maven project with the [ICEFaces](http://www.icefaces.org/) [JSF](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/) framework (for NetBeans or [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/)). Have you found one or information about 'work in progress'?

Comment: Found one at http://code.google.com/p/icefaces-webapp-archetype/ - happy new year 2010!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone's created an [ICEFaces/Seam archetype](http://ctpjava.blogspot.com/2009/07/jboss-seam-archetype-now-with-icefaces.html), it's not available on any standard repositories to my knowledge though. The blog provides details of how to connect to their repository, which is backed by [googlecode.com](http://ctpjava.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repository).

Is this what you're after or are you looking for a standalone ICEfaces archetype?

If you can provide a bit more detail for what you're interested in I might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Not a real archetype yet,but maybe an example how to do it in context to AppFuse:

http://icefusion.googlecode.com

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any arhetype for icefaces on Maven but you can get running sample from [this site](http://dev.nielsvk.com/2008/05/icefaces-and-maven-2.html). And also you can easily integrate Icefaces into Seam Framework. I think this is the best solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.onehippo</groupId>
<artifactId>icefaces-maven</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>icefaces-maven</name>
<url>http://blogs.hippo.nl/niels</url>

<build>
    <finalName>icefaces-maven</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.8</version>
            <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jboss</id>
        <url>http://repository.jboss.com/maven2</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>myfaces-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.icefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>icefaces</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
                <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.icefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>icefaces-comps</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
                <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a Maven archetype to easily get a working IceFaces project mainly under Netbeans:

http://code.google.com/p/icefaces-webapp-archetype/

(created August 2009)